# Find the value of $m+n+p$ if $a^{\frac{1}{m}}= b^{\frac{1}{n}} = c^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and $abc = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, substitution

If $a^{\frac{1}{m}}= b^{\frac{1}{mn}} = c^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and $abc = 1$, then find the value of $m+n+p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a^{\frac{1}{m}}=k$.

Hence,
$$1=abc=k^m\cdot k^n\cdot k^p=k^{m+n+p}$$
Thus, $m+n+p=0$ or $k=1$.

For $k=1$ we have $a=b=c=1$ and we can not  find a value of $m+n+p$.

Comment: or $a=b=c=1\phantom{}$.

Comment: Define $k$  what if $a,b,c=\pm1$

Comment: How is abc=k^(m+n+p)?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee For $a=-1$ our problem is not defined.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown I saw it. I fixed my post. Thank you.

Comment: @uvrichest I fixed my post for you. See now please.